# change editor and author of a document via powershell CSOM

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom

I am wanting to change the editor and author of a document in a document library in O365 using CSOM powershell. I have managed to change the dates like this :

```
$Upload = $List.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$ListItem = $Upload.ListItemAllFields;

$Listitem["Modified"] = "2013-07-02T00:00:00"
$Listitem["Created"] = "2013-07-02T00:00:00"

$ListItem.Update()
$Context.Load($Upload)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

but I am stuck with how to add people as `$Listitem["Editor"] = "John Smith"` doesn't work

Comment: Do you want to set "Editor" and "Author"(user columns) column or "Created" or "Modified" (date columns)?

Comment: all I have done the create and modified which works correctly I am stuck on getting Editor and Author to work

Answer (score 1):

Author and Editor fields are lookup fields.  If you don't know the User ID you can get it by doing something like:

```
$user = $context.Web.EnsureUser($userEmail)
$context.Load($user)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Then in your code you can set the lookup value. By providing a formatted string as follows:

```
$item["Editor"] = "{0};#{1}" -f $user.Id, $user.LoginName
```

Interestingly, it might seem that using a FieldUserValue is the appropriate way to do this:

```
$userValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue
$userValue.LookupId = $user.Id
$item["Editor"] = $userValue
```

But that fails (or it does for me).

UPDATE: I created a blog with full PowerShell source here: http://www.threewill.com/update-sharepoint-online-system-fields-via-csom/